# need to add contentEditable=false to p tag inside CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, contenteditable, readonly

i need inside my CKEditor some boilerplate verbiage that is not editable, then the rest of the my string information. I concatenate the boilerplate verbiage [which is in a p tag], to a string variable that my CKEditor displays inside a certain div. By the time the verbiage, here:

```
<p id='abc' contentEditable='false'>verbiage</p>
```

... and the string information is displayed on the page, they are deep inside a number of nested tags - within a body with multiple classes. So both the verbiage, which is now in only a p tag with no attributes[they got stripped out], is nested way inside the original body tag [the first body tag, way up in the page] with lots and lots of divs, then finally comes an iframe, then ... the verbiage and string are like this:

```
<body contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="false">
<p>boilerplate verbiage</p>
```

...then the rest of the information is displayed in the editor, inside various spans, etc. i need to make the boilerplate verbiage readonly, contentEditable='false'. Yet everything I try both from the console in Chrome, and in code.... nothing changes that boilerplate verbiage

tag. i have tried various things, including these - perhaps you can see where I need to tweak something; and i hope this will show you things i have tried and that i am run out of options so far:

```
jQuery("body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders").first().contentEditable='false';
jQuery("body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders").attr("readonly", "1");
jQuery("body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders p:first-child").contentEditable='false';
jQuery("body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders").find( "p" ).contentEditable='false';
jQuery("iframe", ".cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders").contents().find("p").contentEditable='false';
jQuery("iframe", "body .cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders").contents().find("p").contentEditable='false';

var editor= jQuery("body", ".cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders");
editor.val(editor.val().replace(/<p>/gi, "<p class='tiny_p'>"))

var editor= jQuery("body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders");
editor.val(editor.val().replace(/<p>/gi, "<p class='tiny_p'>"))
```

yet if i hard code in the Chrome browser, contenteditable="false",
it works perfectly. So, how can i access that p tag and assign it this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on moment and how you want to access, one option to access directly from separate script.

```
CKEDITOR.instances[YOUR_INSTANCE].window.$.document.getElementById("your_p_tag")
```

Note, that it should be done after CKEDITOR initilized

**UPDATE:**

```
CKEDITOR.instances[YOUR_INSTANCE].window.$.document.body.firstChild
```

Comment: Thank you - but you may recall that in the DOM my original p tag defined with an id, is rendered to the page inside the editor's body tag simply as <p>boilerplate verbiage</p> without the id, so there is no id to grab via getElementById. it would be nice to add that id to the "first child of the body.class1.class2.class3..... perhaps using jQuery? not sure how yet.

Comment: @dcparham i updated answer for p tag as first child of body ( like in your original question )

Comment: thank you, SAZ, i tried that but wasn't able to touch that <p> element. so i finally created a new ckeditor using the builder on their site, and added Placeholder. i used my old config.js which had only the tools on the bar that i wanted; so the Placeholder is not on the toolbar now either; yet the code that the Placeholder creates when you add a placeholder to the editor is like this: [[placeholder goes here]] - add the two left ['s and two right ]'s around some data and viola, a yellow-highlighted placeholder, read only. it is troubling that you can delete it, however. no clues how to avoid.